# i wanna access the internet with my tablet via the second device

Tags: bluetooth, internet

I got a tablet without wifi connection, and a device with a SIM card and internet access. I managed to get a Bluetooth connection between those two devices. Now i wanna access the internet with my tablet via the second device. Is there a way given through android to dial into the internet ? I thought about implicit Intents or Bluetooth tethering, but didnt find anything yet.

i hope u got what im asking about ;)

ty in advance

Comment: We can't help without knowing more about the device that has the internet connection, since it's the one that needs software to share the connection. What kind of device is it, and what software does it run?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the other device.

There must be an option for **sharing the internet over bluetooth** in other device's bluetooth connection settings.

If you turn it on, you can connect to internet on your android tablet.